# I want to add Auto_Increment to the first column in my table

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

How do I add the Auto_Increment property to the first column in my table ? This is what I tried but it does not work:

```
"ALTER TABLE `User_ReputationLog` MODIFY `EntryID` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `User_ReputationLog` MODIFY COLUMN `EntryID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```